# Do technology filters not work in jobs?

Tags: bug, status-norepro, stack-overflow-jobs

I've seen other posts about this, but they're old.  That is why I am bringing this topic up in meta.

I have a saved job search that should exclude some technologies (e.g. PHP and Ruby).  However, I still get job results that include these technologies.

Here is the URL to my search:

https://stackoverflow.com/jobs?l=United+States&d=20&u=Miles&r=true&tl=python+flask+asp-classic+vbscript+javascript+css+html&td=ruby+c%2B%2B+ruby-on-rails+c%23+php+salesforce+drupal+bitcoin+ethereum+java+spring+swing&s=90000&c=USD&j=permanent&cd=Soshace

You'll see what tech I have tried to exclude; yet, jobs with those tech are still included in my results.

I'm using Chrome 79 with Windows 10 64-bit with no extensions.

**Edit 1 (2020-02-20 13:48 CDT)**

Compensation filters do not work, either.  My search has $90,000 as a criteria, but jobs for $35-50k are showing up.

Answer (score 3):

I wasn't able to replicate either search issue.

1. The disliked tag section doesn't supersede any other search filter in your query.
2. I don't see any jobs under $90k in the search results.

For example:

- "Senior C++ Developer/Engineer (Senior, Remote)" shows up because it offers remote work even though it's tagged c++.
- "Senior DevOps Engineer (Contract, Remote)" because it offers remote work and it's tagged python which is in your liked tag filter.

That said, we don't only return results from your filter. About halfway down the page, you'll see a section that's titled "You might be interested in these jobs:". These are results that don't exactly match your query, but they're close. I admit the text is pretty small.

As far as I can tell, the search is working correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Picking up on @Juice's answer, this was the exact same save for me as well so I created a TamperMonkey script to better highlight the "You might be interested in these jobs" section. I can now see it from a mile away.

The script:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         StackOverflow jobs splitter highlight
// @match        https://stackoverflow.com/jobs*
// @run-at       document-end
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==

(function() {
    'use strict';

    var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('ml24 mb4');

    if ( elements.length === 1 ) {
        var cssText =
            "font-size: 2rem;"
        + "color: white;"
        + "background-color: red;"
        + "text-align: center;"
        + "padding: 12rem 5px;"
        ;

        elements[0].style.cssText = cssText;
    }
})();
```

The result:

[image]